# How to show xUnit tests in the order they are written and not alphabetically?

Tags: visual-studio, bdd, xunit.net

I am using test runner in Visual studio 2012 with xUnit and I noticed the tests are shown in Test Explorer alphabetically.

So I build my first test, then write my second etc... so I would like my tests shown in that order (note my tests are independent).

Is there a setting that allows me to do this?

Comment: No; the tests are discovered in higgeldy piggeldy order based on what the compiler and the reflection kick out. Then they are run in random order (an xUnit feature). Thus while it may seem natural to you that they should be in order of decl, there are lots of reasons this shouldnt be the case. Having said all of that, it's more than likely the VS test runner's sorting effect (feel free to clarify whether you are aware of the grouping options in the UI and/or why you feel this ordering is so important to have)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had my first test as 'Given a playerset(folder) which has one subset playerset with one player then one player playlist is returned'. So I then test other permutations as they get more complex. So when I come back at a later date to review them, I would like to read them from easier to more complex tests.

Comment: @BradWilson can you confirm my assumptions in this please? Right, not a mad ask. I guess I'd be logging a uservoice issue on the VS runner then to be able to order the test list by discovery order (I'm guessing that while it's not an explicit requirement the xunit discoverer will likely yield them in your desired order). What I would not be doing though is requiring the conflation of 1. vs running the test list in run order 2. xunit running the tests in raw discovery order. The reason for this separation is that xunit intentionally runs (and should run) tests in random order

Comment: Does a vs testlist (which I hate!) [allow reordering] retain its ordering when reloaded? If so, perhaps you could abuse this as a workaround?